# How to express my dictionary details as array in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

This is the follow up of this question that i have asked previously [How do i find the last row index of each duplicates within the same column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60860839/how-do-i-find-the-last-row-index-of-each-duplicates-within-the-same-column). Currently i am trying to extract each of the duplicated names that i have already found, stored under the Key of the dictionary. But how do i extract and express them in the form of array using the Key that i have found previously? Because ultimately i want to use the size of the array as one of the condition to copy the entire column of duplicated names into another worksheet but i couldn't express the Key here such that they have an array size.

edit: What i mean by extract each of the duplicated name is where the arr size should be 4 as arr= ("John","trump","alice","sarah") if i managed to extract them from dict to array

```
Dim target as long

For Target = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
```

picture of the dictionary details that checks for duplicated name

```
Debug.Print Key, Dict(Key), Rng.Address
```

'dict(key) refers to the lastrow index of duplicated names, Key refers to the name of duplicated name, Rng.address refers to the range where each duplicated name lies.

[image]

the purpose of finding array in the form of  arr=("John","trump","alice","sarah")

Because i ultimately, i wanted to copy and paste the entire duplicate into different worksheets for example, entire row that consists of the name john into john worksheet, entire row that consists of the name sarah into sarah worksheet. Hence, my plan layout is to find their row index, then use arrays to check whether their name exists in arr= ("john","sarah","alice","trump"), and if they exist, proceed to copy and paste them into their respective worksheet. Hence, after i got my rowindex from dict, i tried to integrate them into the arr parts which leads me to this problem..

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `dict.count`?

Comment: `dict.Keys` will return an array of keys - is that what you're after? `count` returns the number of items in the dictionary.

Comment: @SJR sorry i think i didn't explain clearly, i need the Arr in For Target = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr) to be just the names that are duplicated so arr = ("john","trump","Alice","Sarah") so size of arr=4.  But i cant list them down as like what i shown now because earlier on im checking for duplicated names which assume i have no clue which names are duplicated..

Comment: oh wait does dict.count gives me 4 here?

Comment: but still how do i express details from dict into arr = ("john","trump","Alice","Sarah") by extracting them from dictionary put them into an array as shown here?

Comment: I think you need to post more code as I'm not clear about your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're after, although I don't see why you need an array.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, dict As Object, i As Long, v

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each r In Range("A1:A9")
    dict(r.Value) = r.Address
Next r

v = dict.keys 'put the keys into an array (seems redundant to me)

For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
    MsgBox v(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: i have made an explanation on the reasons for using dict and array together though this is the only method that i can think of  to copy and paste duplicate into their respective worksheets..

Comment: so i googled this method of copy and paste duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180506/how-do-i-copy-and-paste-data-to-worksheets-that-i-created-in-vba-using-for-loop  and wanted to integrate it with dict and arrays..

Comment: but how do i store the names that is displayed in msgbox and use it on the arr= (".....")  ?

Comment: anyways, my previous code i have used set dict=new dictionary and dict as dictionary so should i just replaced my previous ones with yours?

Comment: It's `v = dict.keys`, I don't know how else to say it!

Answer (score 1):

To fill a column with the keys use [transpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose).

```vb
Sub demo()

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.Add "A", 1
    dict.Add "B", 1
    dict.Add "C", 1

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys)

End Sub
```

Update:
There is no need to copy the duplicate names from the dictionary keys into an array and then use the array to check if a value is a duplicate, the dictionary exists(name) method does that for you.

By using a dictionary for the start row and another for the end row, it is straightforward to determine the range of duplicate rows for each name and copy that range to a new sheet without rescanning column A checking if the cell value exist in an array of 'duplicate names'.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyDuplicates()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim irow As Long, iLastRow As Long

    Dim dictFirstRow As Object, dictLastRow As Object, sKey As String
    Set dictFirstRow = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' first row for name
    Set dictLastRow = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' last row for name

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    iLastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' build dictionaries
    For irow = 1 To iLastRow
        sKey = ws.Cells(irow, 1)
        If dictFirstRow.exists(sKey) Then
           dictLastRow(sKey) = irow
        Else
           dictFirstRow.Add sKey, irow
           dictLastRow.Add sKey, irow
        End If
    Next

    ' copy range of duplicates
    Dim k, iFirstRow As Long, rng As Range, wsNew As Worksheet
    For Each k In dictFirstRow.keys

        iFirstRow = dictFirstRow(k)
        iLastRow = dictLastRow(k)

        ' only copy duplicates
        If iLastRow > iFirstRow Then
            Set wsNew = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
            wsNew.Name = k

            Set rng = ws.Rows(iFirstRow & ":" & iLastRow).EntireRow
            rng.Copy wsNew.Range("A1")
            Debug.Print k, iFirstRow, iLastRow, rng.Address
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: my question is more on towards how to express arr = ("john","trump","Alice","Sarah")  in the form of dictionary terms without manually using the names in the brackets so that i can get the size of array =4 which can be use later on for another condition  For Target = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)

Comment: but still how do i express arr = ("john","trump","Alice","Sarah") by extracting them from dictionary and put them into an array as shown here?

Comment: exactly what i wanted, can you post this on this link as well so that i can accept it as an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878328/how-to-copy-entire-rows-based-on-column-a-duplicated-name-to-its-respective-work